# Refreshing listview and checkboxes in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, checkbox, jquery-mobile-listview

I am adding `<li>` and `checkBoxes` dynamically in web page i am usinh `JQuery Mobile` but after adding it cannot view properly i tried with `$('#contactList').listview('refresh')` but it shows error that `listview is not a function` 
Here is my HTML Part

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search" id="contactList">
                </ul>
```

and JS Part that i add dynamically is

```
$('#contactList').append('<li>\
                    <input type="checkbox" name="'+contactId+'" id="'+contactId+'" class="custom" />\
                    <label for="checkbox-5a">\
                        <span class="span2 contact-name">\
                        '+contactName+'\
                        </span>\
                        <span class="contact-image">\
                            <img src="'+contactImage+'"/>\
                        </span>\
                    </label>\
                </li>')
```

Now how i refresh both `li` and `check boxes` so they looks correctly

Update:: My Page Head is like this

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>                      <!-- Scripts n CSS  -->
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>               <!-- for J Query Mobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />


<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- For BootStrap -->

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/><!-- Must Same Order -->

<!-- HTML5 shim for IE backwards compatibility -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- User Generated JS Files -->
<script src="lib/work-space.js"></script>
<script src="lib/contactsFile.js"></script>
```

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/pBTrn/

Comment: yes i want this and i already try this but it shows me an error

`TypeError: $(...).append(...).listview is not a function`

Comment: I also update my question and include the head part of page

Comment: remove jquery-ui or place it before jqm in head, and try again.

Comment: i removed jquery-ui but same issue

Comment: please try the same code I have in the demo. `$('#contactList').append('<li><input type="checkbox" name="chkbx1" id="test" class="custom" /><label for="test"><span class="span2 contact-name">Checkbox</span><span class="contact-image"><img src="http://www.theaa.com/resources/images/maps/shell-logo-50sq.gif"/></span></label></li>').listview('refresh');` just for testing purposes.

Comment: i wrote the same code to append but it shows the code but not styling properly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38320/discussion-between-omar-and-blu-angel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use same name in `label-for` as the `checkbox` name

your code is

```
$('#contactList').append('<li>\
                <input type="checkbox" name="'+contactId+'" id="'+contactId+'" class="custom" />\
                <label for="checkbox-5a">\
                    <span class="span2 contact-name">\
                    '+contactName+'\
                    </span>\
                    <span class="contact-image">\
                        <img src="'+contactImage+'"/>\
                    </span>\
                </label>\
            </li>')
```

But you should write this

```
$('#contactList').append('<li>\
                <input type="checkbox" name="'+contactId+'" id="'+contactId+'" class="custom" />\
                <label for="'+contactId+'">\
                    <span class="span2 contact-name">\
                    '+contactName+'\
                    </span>\
                    <span class="contact-image">\
                        <img src="'+contactImage+'"/>\
                    </span>\
                </label>\
            </li>')
```